Uniform distribution over the set of equipartition of $[0,1]$?
Can we place a formal probability space on the intuitive idea of a uniform probability distribution over the sets of $[0,1]$ of measure $\frac12$?
It sounds like the Haar measure would be helpful (the space of such sets is homogeneous, acted upon by the measure-preserving bijections of $[0,1]$), but it also does not sound locally compact. This is also related to drawing uncountably many Bernoulli random variables (one for each $x\in[0,1]$).
